# Reading JSON object from Python resulting in TypeError

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read JSON from Python. Here is my JSON object returned from geocode request:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Race Course Lane",
               "short_name" : "Race Course Ln",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Little India",
               "short_name" : "Little India",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Singapore",
               "short_name" : "Singapore",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Singapore",
               "short_name" : "SG",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Race Course Ln, Singapore",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 1.3103311,
                  "lng" : 103.85354
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 1.3091323,
                  "lng" : 103.8523656
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 1.3097033,
               "lng" : 103.8529918
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 1.311080680291502,
                  "lng" : 103.8543017802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 1.308382719708498,
                  "lng" : 103.8516038197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJe5XzBMcZ2jERclOJt-xVp_o",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I am trying to get the formatted_address and lat lng under geometry. Here is my code:

```
json_data = requests.get(url).json()

formatted_address = json_data['results'][0]['formatted_address']
print(formatted_address)
for each in json_data['results'][0]['geometry']:
    print(each['lat'])
```

I managed to print out the formatted address but I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Desktop\test.py", line 16, in <module>
print(each['lat'])
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `for x in d['results'][0]['geometry']` results in iteration over keys.

Comment: And, since the keys are strings, `str[str]` is going to error out. What you'd probably want is: `x = json_data['results'][0]['geometry']; for each in x: x[each]['lat']`

Comment: Now, this will result in another error, because not all key-value pairs have dicts with a lat key. Please take another look at your JSON and figure out _where_ you want to extract coordinates form. `location`?

Comment: I wanted to extract Race Course Ln, Singapore, 1.3097033, 103.8529918. The lat lng is the one under location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_data['results'][0]['geometry']` is a `_dict_`. This means that, `for x in json_data['results'][0]['geometry']` will result in iteration over the keys, where `x` is a loop variable that is assigned a key (string). Here's an example -

```
d = {'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd'}

for each in d:
     print(x)   

a
c
```

Since `each` is a string, `each['lat']` would be an invalid operation (since you can't index a string with anything besides an integer).

---

Observe the structure of your JSON file  -

```
{
    "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
    ...

    "location": {
        "lng": 103.8529918,
        "lat": 1.3097033
    }
}
```

Carefully observe that only `location` has a dict with `lat` and `lng` keys associated with it. If all you want are these values, then just index them directly. A loop is not needed.

```
x = json_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
lat, lng = x['lat'], x['lng']
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Hey but just a quick check with you. I kept getting this error message for some address: IndexError: list index out of range. For example, for address A, when I ran the first time, it throw me this error message. Then I ran again for the second time, it return me the lat lng. Then I ran it for the third time, I am getting the error message again. Could it because I am iterating thru each address too fast before the response even come back?

Comment: @hyperfkcb No, that would never happen. The response will always be received before iteration begins. My suggestion is to use a try-except block to catch the error and print out the response in that situation to see where you're going wrong.